# How to submit a form after submitting other form?

Tags: html, forms, jsp, submit, form-submit

I'm working with html and jsp, and I'm trying to do a custom search that performs the same action as that of a catalog search that is on another page. I have two pages:

- There is a page (outside my app, so I can't modify at all) that is a catalog search:

  ```
  <form name="formulario" id="formulario" method="post" action="Main">
      <input tabindex="116" size="55" id="txtSimpleSearch" name="txtSimpleSearch">
      <input value="Search" type="submit" name="btnSearch" tabindex="102">
  </form>
  ```
- I have to create a page in my app that works as a custom search in that catalog seach. So I created this form:

  ```
  <form method="post" rel="external" action="http://example.com/pages/SimpleSearch" target="_blank">
      <fieldset> 
          <label for="txt"><span class="label">Text:</span>
          <input name="txtSimpleSearch" id="txt" type="text"></label>   
      </fieldset>
      <div>
          <input class="boton" value="Search" type="submit">
      </div>
  </form>
  ```

The action of the second form (my page) goes to the catalog search, with the value of txt input, but it isn't do the search on the first page (the catalog search page not execute the submit of the form formulario).

Maybe I could get the form of the catalog search page and do the submit using Javascript? Or isn't possible?

Thanks.

Comment: I think you're having a wrong approach by creating another form on another page to re-submit. Why don't you use the submitted data from the first form to display the catalog search?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use the same `name` attributes for your input, so the page will be able to get the search value.

```
<form method="post" rel="external" action="http://example.com/pages/SimpleSearch" target="_blank">
    <fieldset> 
        <label for="txt"><span class="label">Text:</span>
        <input name="txtSimpleSearch" id="txt" type="text"></label>   
    </fieldset>
    <div>
        <input class="boton" value="Search" type="submit" name="btnSearch">
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks, it's true, I have confused at posting it, but in my code the name changes dynamically with jsp, and in this case the input takes the value txtSimpleSearch.

Comment: The submit of my page works, and goes to the page where is the catalog search, with the txtSimpleSearch input with the value loaded, but I'd like to do the search as the catalog search page does (submit also the second form).

Comment: You want to submit a form on another page?

Comment: Yes, I do not even know if it is possible, but is what I would like to do.

Answer (score 0):

change input type='submit' to type='button' , add attribute to the input onclick='actionSubmitForm1()' then use javascript submit

```
document.forms["myform"].submit();
```

then submit you'rs second form

```
document.forms["myform2"].submit();
```

Comment: Thanks, but one question, do I have access to the elements of the page where is the search catalog, simply using document? Because they are two different pages

Comment: jquery: $("#myform").submit(); then $("myform2").submit();